# I have a problem trying to compile a project using cmake and vcpkg

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to do everything right, firstly I use my command to add the targets with the command `cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../../vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake ..`

and then I use the command
`make -j 16`

The error is this one, I really don't know what I could be doing wrong, this error happens after my compilation file reaches 100% it reaches 100% and then it looks like this, when it reaches 100% it would have to generate me the compiled file, however it doesn't.
error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcryptopp-static: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/otbr.dir/build.make:1525: bin/otbr] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:98: src/CMakeFiles/otbr.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

logs: https://pastebin.com/aixvz9gj
CmakeList.txt: https://pastebin.com/5CQ8mM8g

I've tried everything, even searching on other sites but I haven't found anything.

Comment: It looks like you're missing a library on your computer, `ld` - which is the linker - is saying that `cryptopp-static` doesn't exist on the system. It's either something you missed to build - or a dependency that needs to be installed

Comment: You have not provided enough information for anyone to offer more than generic help. Please see [ask], [tour], and [mre]. I would expect to see, at a minimum, your CMakeLists.txt file. I would also recommend using vcpkg in manifest mode instead. vcpkg can also be packaged in your project as a git submodule. This would allow anyone to clone your project and have the proper dependencies installed locally for them.

Comment: A muito obrigado irei fazer as alterações então.

Comment: Why use pastebin? Why not include it in the question itself?

Comment: Where should cryptopp-static come from? Did you try installing it with vcpkg? If so, you did not show us that part. Nor why you think it would be static.